# What factors might cause JS to view an iFrame and child as being from different origins when they are located in the same root folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Background:** This question is in regards to an iFrame and its child document.

According to the MDN, [HTMLIFrameElement.contentDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) when `element.contentDocument` returns `null` it indicates that JS considers that the document that contains the iFrame and the child document it references are not in the same origin.

> If the iframe and the iframe's parent document are Same Origin,
> returns a Document (that is, the active document in the inline frame's
> nested browsing context), else returns **null**.

[Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) indicates that two URLs have the same origin if they share the same "scheme/host/port tuple".

> Two URLs have the same origin if the protocol, port (if specified),
> and host are the same for both.

However, in the simplified example below all of the documents are stored in the same root directory on my hard drive and accessed through an Express server.

**Question:** The variable `interiorParagraph` in `experiment.js` always ends up with the value `null` instead of a reference to the document.   I believe this indicates they aren't in the same origin, but I'm not entirely certain because I haven't been able to make any headway.  Why am I not getting the result I expected?

**Express:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views/public')));
app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('app listening');
});
```

**index.ejs**

```
<head>
    <script src="/js/experiment.js" type="module" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <iframe src="/html/interior.html" data-iframe></iframe>

</body>
```

**interior.html**

```
<body>
    
    <p data-interior>Hello World</p>

</body>
```

**experiment.js**

```
const iframe = document.querySelector('[data-iframe]');
const interiorParagraph = iframe.contentDocument.querySelector('[data-interior]');

alert(interiorParagraph);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a day of testing and practically giving up I just found the solution.

I simply needed to wait for the `load` event to fire before I referenced the child document.  I thought both documents loaded instantly and I hadn't considered that this might be an async issue.

```
iframe.addEventListener('load', () => {
    // do stuff here
});
```

Comment: Great work!  Even though the fix was simple, it's actually a difficult problem to debug if you've not seen it before. +1

Comment: Thanks, to me that one was mind boggling!  I've run into loading issues in regards to timing before but I had never used an iFrame and so I never thought to connect the two.  Going forward I'm going to look for async issues right from the start.